# Is there a way to know the total development of a specific country?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In my case, I'm playing Ming and I want to avoid the [Unguarded Nomadic Frontier](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Unguarded_Nomadic_Frontier) disaster caused by a neighboring country that is a Horde and has 300 development. I know there is a map mode that shows development for each province, but not for the entire country.

Is there a way to know the total development of a specific country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find that information in the **Ledger** (Hotkey: L).

`Ledger -> Country -> Country -> Development Column`

[image]